# Average height of a point in half circle

Tags: calculus

I am watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9a_NHXrBcg) video and I cannot understand the differences in what we are calculating in both examples. In Ex 2 we use circle equation and in Ex 3 we use sine function. I do not really understand the differences of what we are trying to calculate here and why we are using two different functions.
Thanks 
[image]

and 
[image]

EDIT: so in video it says that Ex 2 is with respect to $x$ while Ex 3 is with respect to  $\Theta$. But it does not help me much in understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\theta$ is not a linear function of $x$. So the averages are different. It may be easier to understand if we think about the discrete case. For example, we take only 5 points and find the average.

If we take the average over $\theta$, we will take $\theta=0$, $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $\pi$. The corresponding heights are $0$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $1$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $0$ respectively.

If we take the average over $x$, we will take $x=-1$, $\frac{-1}{2}$, $0$, $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$. The corresponding heights are $0$, $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $1$, $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $0$ respectively.

The averages are different.

Loosely speaking, the first formula is to find the average length of the red line segments and the second formula is to find the average length of the blue line segments.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I still do not understand why the averages are different. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Simple and clear.+1